# How to loop through all tables in SSIS and export each one to a flat file named after the table (e.g. table1.txt)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, export, ssis

Questions says it all.

Using SSIS I want to be able to loop through all the tables in a given database.  For each table I want to be able to export all of the data to a flat file (.txt file) that is pipe-delimited and includes column names (I assume using a flat file destination task).

Is this possible? And if so, how to do it?

Thanks - wg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General pattern would be

1) Create an [Execute SQL task](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280492.aspx) that dumps a table list into an object variable

2) [Shred the recordset](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Shredding-a-Recordset.aspx) object into schema and table name variables

3) Perform an Execute Process Task to [BCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189569.aspx) the data into files